# Does encrypting a partition prevent data recovery?

Tags: partitioning, ssd, encryption, data-recovery, storage

When a partition on a drive is *not* encrypted, and a file is accidentally deleted, it is relatively easy to restore the data.  This is because, for most file systems, a delete operation simply marks the file as deleted, but does not actually delete the data.

What about for encrypted partitions?  Since all the data on the partition is encrypted, it seems that it would make any accidentally deleted data virtually impossible to recover.  Is this the case?

Comment: Never was in such a case but if the disk is encrypted, then it will be difficult to retrieve with a tool outside the system unless it know how to decrypt the disk. I would assume that if you use a tool like Recuva while under Windows on that encrypted disk, then it should work. You could try with a test file you create and delete shortly after.

Answer (score 0):

With solutions like LUKS on Linux where encryption and file-system are separated, you can decrypt the partition and make it readable to some tool like `extundelete`. If the filesystem integrates the encryption logic, the undelete tool must deal with the encryption logic. This seems to be possible however (here Windows/bitlocker encryption) : https://www.m3datarecovery.com/bitlocker-drive-data-recovery/recover-deleted-files-from-bitlocker-encrypted-drive.html